# There is a gap between my nav bar and the top of my page but only on some pages

Tags: html, css, nav

Here is the HTML, the thing is the nav bar on my first main page works fine but all the other pages have a gap in between the top and the nav bar, its really annoying.

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
    body {
      margin: 0px;
    }
    
    .purchback {
      background-image: url(../IMAGES/egg.png);
      background-size: auto;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    
    .aboutback {
      background-image: url(../IMAGES/farm.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    
    .indexback {
      background-image: url(../IMAGES/potato.jpg), url(../IMAGES/chipsf.jpg);
      background-size: contain, contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    }
    
    .hap {
      height: 280px;
      width: 300px;
    }
    
    html {
      margin-top: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    head{
    }
    
    h2 {
      color: white;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
      border: solid white 3px;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 5px 50px 300px 5px;
      font-family: cursive;
      font-weight: lighter;
      margin: 0;
      text-align: left;
    }
    p {
      color: black;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    .logo {
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
      padding:-10px -10px -10px -10px;
      float: right;
    }
    
    .heading {
      text-align: center;
      font-family: impact;
      color: white;
      font-weight: lighter;
      padding-right: 10px;
      padding-top: 200px;
      border-bottom: solid white 4px;
      padding-bottom: 17px;
    }
    
    .information {
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      font-family: impact;
      font-weight: lighter;
      font-size: 20px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    .chips {
     width: 400px;
     height: 550px;
     padding-top: 40px;
     padding-left: 20px;
    }
    
    .carbless {
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      height: 300px;
      width: 230px;
      padding-top: 60px;
      margin-left: -15px;
      position: sticky;
    }
    
    .carbless:hover {
      border: solid white 3px;
      background-color: rgba(100, 0, 100, 0.5);
    }
    
    .bigg:hover {
      border: solid white 3px;
      background-color: rgba(100, 0, 100, 0.5);
    }
    
    .bigg {
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      height: 330px;
      width: 250px;
      padding-top: 60px;
      margin-left: -9px;
      position: sticky;
    }
    
    background-image {
      width: 800px;
      height: 500px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    
    nav {
      background-color: rgb(200,180,90);
      padding: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: fixed;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .purchase {
      text-align: center;
      font-family: impact;
      color: white;
      font-weight: lighter;
      padding-right: 10px;
      padding-top: 80px;
      border-bottom: solid white 4px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    nav > ul > li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 11px;
      color: white;
      font-family: impact;
      font-size: 30px;
      padding: 5px 40px 5px 40px;
      font-weight: lighter;
    }
    
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    
    }
    
    nav > ul > li > a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
    }
    
    nav > ul {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    
    nav > ul > li > a:hover {
      color: grey;
      border: -5px white solid;
    }
    
    section {
      margin-left: 500px;
      margin-top: -330px;
      color: white;
      font-family: impact;
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 55px;
    }
    
    nav > ul > li > ul {
      background-color: rgb(200,180,90);
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
      display: block;
      border: -5px white solid;
    }
    
    .abouttext {
      margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
      padding: 100px 0px 100px 40px;
      font-family:consolas;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      color: white;
    }
    
    nav > ul > li:hover {
      border: -5px solid white;
    
    }
    
    footer {
      color: white;
      padding-top: 30px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/master.css">
    </head>
    <body class="purchback">
    
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="ABOUT.html#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="purchase.html#">PURCHASE</a></li>
            <li><a href="videos.html#">VIDEOS</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html#">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#"><img class="logo"src="IMAGES/logo.png" alt="logo"></a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    
        <h1 class="purchase" style="padding-top: -30">purchase our products</h1>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

And here is the CSS, sorry if it is messy/bad this is my first time making a website.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `margin` for `.purchase`

```
.purchase {
   text-align: center;
   font-family: impact;
   color: white;
   font-weight: lighter;
   padding-right: 10px;
   padding-top: 80px;
   border-bottom: solid white 4px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   margin:0; /*Add this*/
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
    body {
      margin: 0px;
    }
    
    .purchback {
      background-image: url(../IMAGES/egg.png);
      background-size: auto;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    
    .aboutback {
      background-image: url(../IMAGES/farm.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    
    .indexback {
      background-image: url(../IMAGES/potato.jpg), url(../IMAGES/chipsf.jpg);
      background-size: contain, contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    }
    
    .hap {
      height: 280px;
      width: 300px;
    }
    
    html {
      margin-top: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    head{
    }
    
    h2 {
      color: white;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
      border: solid white 3px;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 5px 50px 300px 5px;
      font-family: cursive;
      font-weight: lighter;
      margin: 0;
      text-align: left;
    }
    p {
      color: black;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    .logo {
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
      padding:-10px -10px -10px -10px;
      float: right;
    }
    
    .heading {
      text-align: center;
      font-family: impact;
      color: white;
      font-weight: lighter;
      padding-right: 10px;
      padding-top: 200px;
      border-bottom: solid white 4px;
      padding-bottom: 17px;
    }
    
    .information {
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      font-family: impact;
      font-weight: lighter;
      font-size: 20px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    .chips {
     width: 400px;
     height: 550px;
     padding-top: 40px;
     padding-left: 20px;
    }
    
    .carbless {
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      height: 300px;
      width: 230px;
      padding-top: 60px;
      margin-left: -15px;
      position: sticky;
    }
    
    .carbless:hover {
      border: solid white 3px;
      background-color: rgba(100, 0, 100, 0.5);
    }
    
    .bigg:hover {
      border: solid white 3px;
      background-color: rgba(100, 0, 100, 0.5);
    }
    
    .bigg {
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      height: 330px;
      width: 250px;
      padding-top: 60px;
      margin-left: -9px;
      position: sticky;
    }
    
    background-image {
      width: 800px;
      height: 500px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    
    nav {
      background-color: rgb(200,180,90);
      padding: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: fixed;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .purchase {
      text-align: center;
      font-family: impact;
      color: #000;
      font-weight: lighter;
      padding-right: 10px;
      padding-top: 80px;
      border-bottom: solid white 4px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      margin:0;
    }
    
    nav > ul > li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 11px;
      color: white;
      font-family: impact;
      font-size: 30px;
      padding: 5px 40px 5px 40px;
      font-weight: lighter;
    }
    
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    
    }
    
    nav > ul > li > a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
    }
    
    nav > ul {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    
    nav > ul > li > a:hover {
      color: grey;
      border: -5px white solid;
    }
    
    section {
      margin-left: 500px;
      margin-top: -330px;
      color: white;
      font-family: impact;
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 55px;
    }
    
    nav > ul > li > ul {
      background-color: rgb(200,180,90);
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
      display: block;
      border: -5px white solid;
    }
    
    .abouttext {
      margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
      padding: 100px 0px 100px 40px;
      font-family:consolas;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      color: white;
    }
    
    nav > ul > li:hover {
      border: -5px solid white;
    
    }
    
    footer {
      color: white;
      padding-top: 30px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/master.css">
    </head>
    <body class="purchback">
    
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="ABOUT.html#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="purchase.html#">PURCHASE</a></li>
            <li><a href="videos.html#">VIDEOS</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html#">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#"><img class="logo"src="IMAGES/logo.png" alt="logo"></a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    
        <h1 class="purchase" style="padding-top: -30">purchase our products</h1>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```